# Drop Columns columns that have been filled in

Tags: r, header, drop

I'm loading a lot of data into R from CSVs.  The CSVs contain columns with empty headers, and I would like to drop those columns from my data set.  I've done some searching and I haven't found a good way to do this.  R fills the columns with X2, X3, etc.  I don't want to remove based on X, because they might drop some columns that I need.  I have about 200 CVS that I need to load here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the text file of a sample csv I used to work through this.  In my actual data, the blank columns don't always occur in every other cell.

```
Name,,Ages,,Color,,Year
Michael,some data,2,some other data,Blue,a third data,2001
Tiffany,some data,3,some other data,Red,a third data,2002
Bryan,some data,4,some other data,Green,a third data,2003
Sarah,some data,5,some other data,Orange,a third data,2004
```

Here's what I'd like to get back.

```
Name,Ages,Color,Year
Michael,2,Blue,2001
Tiffany,3,Red,2002
Bryan,4,Green,2003
Sarah,5,Orange,2004
```

Comment: Please show a smalll reprodcuible example and expected output based on that. thanks.  With `fread` you can `select` columns that are needed

Comment: Thank you, @akrun.  I've added that to the question.

Comment: @akrun, i don't have enough reputation to up vote this, but I REALLY wanted to say thank you.  This worked and will save me about a day's worth of work.  Thank you SO much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a regex to match column names that starts (`^`) with `X` followed by `.` or digits till the end (`$`) of the string in `grep`, specify `invert = TRUE` for negating

```
i1 <- grep('^X([0-9.]+)?$', names(df1), invert = TRUE)
df1[i1]
```

-output

```
#      Name Ages  Color Year
#1 Michael    2   Blue 2001
#2 Tiffany    3    Red 2002
#3   Bryan    4  Green 2003
#4   Sarah    5 Orange 2004
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
      select(!matches('X([0-9.]+)?$'))
```

---

If we have a lots of files to read from the working directory, read it in a `list`, and do the same

```
files <- list.files(pattern = '\\.csv$', full.names = TRUE)
lst1 <- lapply(files, function(x) {
            x1 <- read.csv(x)
           i1 <- grep('^X([0-9.]+)?$', names(x1), invert = TRUE)
           x1[i1]
      })
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("Michael", "Tiffany", "Bryan", "Sarah"
), X = c("some data", "some data", "some data", "some data"), 
    Ages = 2:5, X.1 = c("some other data", "some other data", 
    "some other data", "some other data"), Color = c("Blue", 
    "Red", "Green", "Orange"), X.2 = c("a third data", "a third data", 
    "a third data", "a third data"), Year = 2001:2004),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```